# Which is the spectrum of this operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $T : \ell_2 \to \ell_2$, $T(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n,...) = (0,\frac{x_1}{1},\frac{x_2}{2},\frac{x_3}{3},..., \frac{x_n}{n},...)$. Which is the spectrum of this operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to find the spectrum if you realize that this is a compact operator. To show that it is compact define $T_N(x_n)=(0,\frac  {x_1}1 ,...,\frac {x_N} N,0,0...)$. $T_N$ is of finite rank and hence it is compact. I will let you verify that $\|T-T_N\| \leq \sqrt {\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {k^{2}}} \to 0$. Hence $T$ is compact.

Now non-zero points in the spectrum of a compact operator are eigen values. It is quite easy to see that $Tx=\lambda x$, $\lambda \neq 0$ implies $x_n=0$ for all $n$. Hence there are no non-zero eigen values. It follows that $\sigma (T)=\{0\}$.